# React-native : Firebase how to get all the data

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys how can I request all the data form this kind of DB structure?

[image]

I tried this but it's not working:

```
 var recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('/store');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are on the right track, but missing the retrieval part where `.then()` is used with a callback:

```
var recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('/store');
recentPostsRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  // snapshot.val() is the dictionary with all your keys/values from the '/store' path
  this.setState({ stores: snapshot.val() })
})
```

The [`firebase.database.Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) documentation has a lot of good examples and explanations that can help.